# What would cause a ceiling fan to stop while the light still works?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Installed a new fan/light today.  Wiring appeared to be identical to old fan we removed.

- green ground to green ground on mounting bracket.
- white to white.
- black and blue to black.

Turned it on and all worked well for about 10 minutes at which time the fan blades stopped turning.  Waited about an hour and again it worked well for about 10-15 minutes before fan stopped.  I reviewed the manual and can't see anything indicating I did something incorrectly.  The light continues to work normally.

Answer (score 7):

I would exchange the fan.  It sounds like it is either over heating and there is a safety feature that cuts it out or there is a problem with the motor winding and when it heats up it causes a bad coil wire or a bad connection to open.